# python inserting into Mariadb

Tags: python, sql, mariadb

Good Evening techgods!, wondering if you can help little old me :)
new to python and i'm learning to scrape from video's i'm able to get a tag of it working as an export to excel, what i want to do now, is have it connect to mariadb, because i'm using a raspberry pi for testing :) it seems to be connecting fine, just does not like something and i'm stumped.

so i take the same code and make a little bit of syntax change and i keep getting the following error.

> File "C:/Users/scott/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 37, in
>
> cursor.execute(query) mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB
> server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mariadb

url = 'https://dc.urbanturf.com/pipeline'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
pipeline_items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'pipeline-item'})

rows = []
columns = ['listing title', 'listing url', 'listing image url', 'location', 'Project type', 'Status', 'Size']

for item in pipeline_items:
    # title, image url, listing url
    listing_title = item.a['title']
    listing_url = item.a['href']
    listing_image_url = item.a.img['src']
    for p_tag in item.find_all('p'):
        if not p_tag.h2:
            if p_tag.span.text == 'Location:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_location = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Project type:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_type = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Status:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_status = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Size:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_size = p_tag.text.strip()
    conn = mariadb.connect(host="xxxxxxxx", port=3306, user="xxxxxxxxxx", passwd="xxxxxxxxxxxxx", db="test")
    # Creating a cursor object using the cursor() method
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO Properties(listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_location, 
             property_type, property_status, property_size)"

    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()

    print("Data inserted")
    conn.close()
```

any help is greatly appreciated :)

New code.
no more errors, just cant seem to get the data to import.
it creates empty rows.
the names of the table match that in the current code.

```
    import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mariadb

url = 'https://dc.urbanturf.com/pipeline'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
pipeline_items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'pipeline-item'})

rows = []
columns = ['listing_title', 'listing_url', 'listing_image_url', 'location', 'Project_type', 'Status', 'Sizes']

for item in pipeline_items:
    # title, image url, listing url
    listing_title = item.a['title']
    listing_url = item.a['href']
    listing_image_url = item.a.img['src']
    for p_tag in item.find_all('p'):
        if not p_tag.h2:
            if p_tag.span.text == 'Location:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_location = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Project type:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_type = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Status:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_status = p_tag.text.strip()
            elif p_tag.span.text == 'Size:':
                p_tag.span.extract()
                property_size = p_tag.text.strip()
    conn = mariadb.connect(host="192.168.0.217", port=3306, user="", passwd="", db="test")
    # Create a cursor object using the cursor() method
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO Properties VALUES(listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_location, property_type, property_status, property_size) "
    cursor.execute(query)
    conn.commit()
    print("Data inserted")
    conn.close()
```

Working version encase someone is looking for something similar :)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import mariadb

conn = mariadb.connect(host="192.168.0.217", port=3306, user="", passwd="", db="test")
# Create a cursor object using the cursor() method

url = 'https://dc.urbanturf.com/pipeline'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
pipeline_items = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': 'pipeline-item'})

rows = []
columns = ['listing_title', 'listing_url', 'listing_image_url', 'location', 'Project_type', 'Status', 'Sizes']


try:
        with conn.cursor() as cursor:
            for item in pipeline_items:
                # title, image url, listing url
                listing_title = item.a['title']
                listing_url = item.a['href']
                listing_image_url = item.a.img['src']
                for p_tag in item.find_all('p'):
                    if not p_tag.h2:
                        if p_tag.span.text == 'Location:':
                            p_tag.span.extract()
                            property_location = p_tag.text.strip()
                        elif p_tag.span.text == 'Project type:':
                            p_tag.span.extract()
                            property_type = p_tag.text.strip()
                        elif p_tag.span.text == 'Status:':
                            p_tag.span.extract()
                            property_status = p_tag.text.strip()
                        elif p_tag.span.text == 'Size:':
                            p_tag.span.extract()
                            property_size = p_tag.text.strip()
                cursor = conn.cursor()
                query = "INSERT INTO Properties(listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_type, property_status, property_size) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                value_tuple = (listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_type, property_status, property_size)
                cursor.execute(query, value_tuple)
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Comment: it maybe that you haven't provided *values* to the SQL query for `INSERT INTO`, as that requires `VALUES` after you provide the columns like you have, so for ex, `INSERT INTO Properties (listing_title) VALUES ('nameOfMovieHere');` or you can do it dynamically using the `%` if you are going to provide the VALUE using an API or some other db table.

Comment: Move the "connect" to _outside_ the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide values to be inserted into the table . See ex :

```
    cursor.execute(
    "INSERT INTO employees (first_name,last_name) VALUES (?, ?)", 
    (first_name, last_name))
```

**UPDATED :**
There was syntax error in previous answer , I've changed it to correct syntax

```
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO Properties(listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_type, property_status, property_size) VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,)"
    value_tuple = (listing_title, listing_url, listing_image_url, property_type, property_status, property_size)
    cursor.execute(query,value_tuple)
```

Comment: with your help, im able to get no errors, but its not importing any data. the database is set to varchar 255 so it should be able to accomodate the query.

Comment: I have updated the answer to correct syntax . Review your code .
Also move your `conn = mariadb.connect(host="192.168.0.217", port=3306, user="", passwd="", db="test")` connection statement outside the loop .

Comment: you are Incredible!, i was just about to give up, and you gave me hope again :) this works like a charm :) i'm sooooo happy!

Comment: If your query has been resolved , please mark my answer as correct one and do upvote :)